# On every node update: Error: Cannot find module 'user-agent-parser'

Tags: node.js, sails.js

On every node update I am getting that error

> Error: Cannot find module 'user-agent-parser'

I am using node `v0.12.6`, every time I am going to update I do

`rm -rf node_modules; npm install; sails lift`

and then I get the errors.

So, how to avoid that type of errors after updating ?

Comment: make sure all modules required by your app are in the package.json.

Comment: here are some other sails.js devs here that you can chat with. See if they can help. https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails